# Combining multiple bandstop filters works only sometimes

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, frequency-response, poles-zeros

for a school project, we were supposed to filter out 4 rogue cosine waves of a given frequency. I created a filter of my own by choosing zeroes and poles by hand. Here, I made 4 poles and 4 zeroes (and a conjugated pair to each one):[image]

I put these zeroes in one array, all these poles into another, and by using np.poly on both of these arrays, I made the B and A coefficients of a filter. The resulting filter frequency response was what I expected:

[image]

However, this filter was not perfect enough, so I made a different one using scipy.buttord and scipy.butter. I made four separate bandstop filters, one for each rogue cosine wave. Each bandstop filter had 4 zeroes on the same place and 4 poles around the same-place zeroes (they had their conjugate parts on the other side of the unit circle) like this:

[image]

What I wanted to do next was combine these four filters into one. So what I did was concatenate the four arrays of zeroes into one, then concatenate four different arrays of poles into one. Then, using np.poly, I thought I would receive the coefficients of the resulting filter. However, the frequency response looks like this (obviously wrong):

[image]

I did some reading and I've been unable to see why this happens. If combining multiple filters like this was not possible, why did it work the first time in my handmade filter? If it is possible, why does it not work here, for the generated filter?

edit:

This is how the frequency response of a single filter looks like. The remaining three look the same, except the zero is at different frequencies.

[image]

Comment: how is this "obviously" wrong? Does it not have nulls at the frequencies you need to suppress? I honestly don't understand why that amplitude response should be wrong, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The frequency response should look very similar to the one I made by hand. It should be 1 everywhere except the frequencies I need to filter out (875, 1750, 2625, 3500) where it should be 0.

Comment: hm, to me it looks much better at being constant over most of the range than your manual design. And again, from the plot I really can't say whether your four frequencies are suppressed or not – it's simply not a useful visualization for that, it probably doesn't sample the frequency response at these points, exactly

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited my question, I added the response of a single filter.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought it should be 0 at the frequencies I need to remove (875, 1750, 2625, 3500), whereas from the combined frequency response it is apparent that it does not supress the 1750Hz one, it even amplifies it.

Comment: hm, again, have you *tested* that, have you asked your program to evaluate at exactly 1750 Hz? If that's the case, something is wrong with the tools you're using, or the way you're using it: no matter what, a zero on the unit circle remains a zero, and will definitely cancel your signal. There's no mathematical way around that.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, using np.poly, I thought I would receive the coefficients of the resulting filter.

I'm guessing, that's your problem. With  16 poles this becomes a very high order polynomial which is numerically challenging. Try implementing the filter as cascaded second order sections instead.

If you want to eliminate steady state sine waves with constant frequency, a notch filter is probably a better choice than a bandstop.

Comment: Hmm, this might be the root (no pun intended) of the problem. What do you mean by cascaded second order sections? I've done some googling but was unable to find a precise answer. I assume you mean filtering by each of the four filters in sequence?

Comment: @ampersander: It means to use a cascade of second-order filters, each representing one complex pole and zero pair. Use poles and zeros that are closest to each other.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html. There are three ways to represent filters. Transfer function (b,a); zeroes+poles+gain (zpk) and second order section (sos). Transfer function is generally a bad idea, especially for higher order filters or filters with poles close to the unit circle. If that doesn't ring a bell, ask  separate question.

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you for your answer. It makes sense. However, I asked my Signals and Systems professor about this, and he told me that all I needed to do was convolve all the filters together and the result would be the final filter. I am pretty unsure, because no one mentioned it here.

Comment: Can you post your poles ? How do you calculate the frequency response from the polynomials?